# Add scripts to Scriptable Object form inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following code with MovementTargeting being an abstract class:

```
public class EnemyScriptableObject : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] public MovementTargeting MovementTargeting;
}
```

How can I expose the abstract class so I can drag and drop a MovementTargeting script to the scriptable object? Right now it doesn't appear in the inspector.

Comment: Is your `MovementTargeting` script serialized?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeReference.html

Comment: Yes, I serialized the script. I also added [SerializeReference] to the property and it appears in the inspector this way but there is no selection field where I can assign a script. Only "Movement Targeting" appears.

Comment: Maybe you need to instantiate `MovementTargeting` script in order to assign it?